# To sum the data of a column called wages

Tags: php, undefined

To sum the data of a column

Here is the code snippet for the problem

```
            if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event'])){
                $total1= 1;
                if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event2'])){
                    $total2 = 1;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }else{
                    $total2 = 0;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $total1= 0;
                if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event2'])){
                    $total2 = 1;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }else{
                    $total2 = 0;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }

                }

            }

            $total4 = $total1 * 10;
            $total5 += $total4; //here is the problem i think
```

still new at this please modify if the code not efficient

The output is there but still an error showed in the output.

Notice: Undefined variable: total5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\S.T.E.M\account.php on line 442

Total = RM 80

Comment: I don't know `php`, but I think directly using `+=` with an undeclared variable(`$total5`) is not allowed here.

Comment: so i have declared the variable($total5 = 0) there is no error but the output is incorrect, but when there is no declaration the output is correct but there an error undefined variable

Comment: Can you write the updated code. And declare `$total5=0` at top.

Comment: Waaa.. i've updated the code. The declaration should not be in the <?php do and it should be before the code. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you pulling this data from a database?